# Updating products on back end not reflected on front end

Tags: magento-2.1, cache, products, category-products, indexing

I have 2 problems and I am not sure if they are related.

First of all I have added a new category with new products, I can click on the Category but no products are displayed. If I go to the actual URL for the product I can see it but it appears as out of stock. However, I have stock management turned off, I have set out of stock items to display, I have gone back and set the quantity of stock to 100, I have even gone and set it to out of stock saved and then set to back in stock but it is still not appearing on the category page and the product page still says out of stock.

Secondly, I have updated the price of another product in another category, when looking at the category page the price is still the old price but when looking at the actual product page the price is updated properly.

I have flushed the cache and reindexed everything and cleared my own browser cache and cookies etc,. but nothing I do seems to make a difference. I feel  like there has to be something cached in the background that is not updating the products on the front end.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

I am using Magento 2.1.11.

Comment: Check time of your server and time in cron_schedule table. Or if you have multiple store mode then check values in the Default Store View.

Comment: Hi @RishabhRkRai thanks for your comment, I have just looked at the table and all jobs are running every minute with a success status so do not think this is the issue.

Comment: I have also gone to the cataloginventory_stock_item table and can see the 'qty' field of the product is correct after I set it to 100. 'is_in_stock' field is also set to 1 for all products but it is still displaying as out of stock on the product page and not visible in the category page - this is only happening for newly created products, old products with 'qty' null display fine

Comment: What I find very strange is my second issue. It is updating the price on the product page but it is still displaying the old price on the category page. So the information is being updated on the back end and I can see it in the database but the front end is still rendering old information, this is why I thought of clearing my own browser cache but it is happening on multiple devices and browsers with cache and cookies cleared

Comment: This has only become an issue since the site went live, moving from braintree sandbox to production and adding an ssl certificate but I don't know how this could be an issue, although I did remove some data from the databases such as fake orders made through the sandbox and the fake customers used to create those

Comment: Ok so I kind of got a bit of a workaround, when I save a product it won't display it will appear as out of stock even though I have the option set to display out of stock items. Leaving the quantity as null I can hit 'save and duplicate' and it will display, literally the exact same options just how the product is saved, is anyone able to explain this?